# Using a template (Jade) to create a table and populate it dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, templates, pug

I am confused on building a simple table in html and populating it dynamically.

I created a simple table in html :

```
<div class="container" style="width:100%;padding:50px">
    <table id="tblItems" class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th>Objet</th>
        <th>Champs</th>
        <th>Demandeur</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Date de la prise en compte</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Then to populate my table, I make an ajax requestto retrieve the data to populate the table :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:3000/suggestions?limit=5&offset=" + offset,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            $.each(response, function(){
                var data = JSON.parse(this.fields);

                ... DOING OTHER STUFF    

                //THIS LOOKS HORRIBLE!! (adding content to my table)
                rows += "<tr><td>" + this.id + "</td><td>" + this.action + "</td><td>" + this.entity + "</td><td style='color:green'>" + fields
                + "</td><td>" + this.requester +  "</td><td>" + this.is_approved + "</td><td>" + this.creation_date +  "</td><td>" + images + "</td></tr>";
            });
          $(rows).appendTo("#tblItems tbody");
    failure: function () {
        console.log("fail");
        $("#tblItems").append(" Error when fetching data please contact administrator");
    }
});
```

The code that I inject to create the table is horrible.
A friend told me that I should use templates. So I looked at it and I created a jade template.

```
doctype
html( lang="en" )
  head
    title Baking Bootstrap Snippets with Jade
    meta( charset='utf-8' )
    meta( http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge' )
    meta( name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' )
    meta( name='description', content='Baking Bootstrap Snippets with Jade' )
    //- Bootswatch Theme
    link(href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.0/flatly/bootstrap.min.css", rel="stylesheet")
  body(style="padding-bottom:10rem;")
    .container
    script( src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js' )
    script( src='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js' )
    script( src='script.js' )
    #container(style='padding:50px;')
      table(id="table",class="table table-striped")
      thead
        tr
          th Id
          th Action
          th Objet
          th Champs
          th Demandeur
          th Status
          th Date de la prise en compte
          th Actions
      tbody
```

Now, my question is the following : how do I populate my table in a "beautiful way"? I'll have to call a javascript file to make my ajax query, but then, how can I populate the table without having to pass an ugly html string which is not readable?

Comment: I think I can answer my own question, I could use mustache.js instead of jade.js : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791312/mustache-template-with-nested-array-of-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can't do this in jade only you need some kind of templating engine.

It needs to be JS based:

- Underscore
- Embedded
- Mustache

There is another way with PHP. Parse the JSON to php and then generate the content. You can also use some of the templating engines for that. *(Some one will disagree that you need  a templating engine when PHP is one)*

My personal recommendation would be:

- Twig
- Plates

Comment: Yeah thank you I figured it out, I was waiting that someone would confirm that, I'll paste an example later